# React Final Form Pass Additional Parameters to Form State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-final-form

[React Final Form](https://final-form.org/react) uses a [render prop pattern](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) in its form component, and I am trying to understand how I can modify it to pass it additional arguments.

According to it's documentation, it [passes the following props](https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/types/FormRenderProps) to the render function - including (crucially) the [FormState](https://final-form.org/docs/final-form/types/FormState).

Let's take a look at my particular implementation, focusing on the render function:

```
<Form
onSubmit={() => {console.log("wow coolio you submitted a form!")}}
initialValues={initData}
validate={validateMyForm}
render={({ handleSubmit, reset, submitting, pristine, values }) => {
formSubmitHandler = async () => {
await handleSubmit()
return values
}
return(
//... form components with the values prop passed into them below
//...i.e. <Part_1_Of_Form values={values}/>
```

If I understand correctly, you will note I destruct the render prop object in the JSX `{({})}` and get the `values` from the FormState.

I then pass them to various modular form components below - like `<Part_1_Of_Form/>` in order to make each part  of the form react to state changes in other parts of the form. But my problem is I want it to react to more than the values. For example, if I want to display a label conditionally based on if another label option (or another option) is selected in another part of the form, I can't access it because I only get access to the values - not the labels.

**Example**, with a currency selection tool to propagate throughout the form using state:

```
<Field 
name="part_one.currency"
component={MyRFFInputSelectComponent}
options={[{value: 'USD', label: '$ (USD)', symbol: '$'}, {value: 'EUR', label: '€ (EUR)', symbol: '€'}]}
required={true}
className="form-control">
</Field>
```

I can pass the value (let's say `USD`) around other parts of the form, using the render props and the `values` part of that returned object - but I don't want to. I want to pass the `symbol` - the value `(USD)` belongs to the database (it's only `USD` because the DB wants it as a string like that) - but the other parts of the form should display the symbol instead of the value once I select my currency in the top part of the form.

Example of what I have to do now elsewhere in the form:

```
<Field
...
append={values['part_one']['currency']}
```

Example of what I want to do:

```
<Field
...
append={symbols['part_one']['currency']}
```

Or maybe even better:

```
<Field
...
append={allFormData(notjustvalues)['part_one']['currency']['symbol']}
```

So that each input that needs a price can show a currency in the appended label.

Does this usecase make sense?

Is there another way to pick up the symbol or a way to add it to the FormState? I think its probably bad for perf to pass something like `allFormData` around just to get one custom symbol. I can't use the symbol for the value because my backend developer will cry.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, your value for `part_one.currency` needs to be the entire `{value: 'USD', label: '$ (USD)', symbol: '$'}` object.

Then you can do `values.part_one.currency.symbol` elsewhere in your form. If you only want the value to be `'USD'` when you submit, you'll need to handle that in your `onSubmit` function. Does that help?